# Formal way of saying "when you are in need"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, formality, politeness

How can I write following in a formal way?

- It will help you when you are in need.
- It will help you when it is required.
- It will help you when needed.
- It will help you when you required to be helped.
- It will help you when you are required to do such task.

**Edit**

A person is denying to perform a task/job on computer and insisting that he only needs to do it for few days and then the job/task will be no more required so i do the job for him. While I am going to request him to do it himself because he may require to do the same due to any reason in future and doing so will make him know how to do that job.

Now i need a formal statement to communicate my concerns to him.

Comment: Your first three sentences are correct, and the first is quite polite/formal. The last two have mistakes. I like the first one. Which do you like best?

Comment: @Susan I am looking for more better and formal. Please point out mistakes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on ell.se

Comment: Could you please say "what" will help you? It's difficult to judge whether your sentences are appropriate or not without context. Thanks!  For example, the verb, help, might be oversimplified and consequently ineffective.

Comment: @Mari-LouA see updated question

Comment: Your edit has improved your question, it's clear that you are talking to a co-worker so you needn't be excessively formal. I would suggest: "By performing/doing this job/duty/task yourself, it will also help you handle any foreseeable problems in the future." I can't offer this as an answer because I have paraphrased your sentences and I am not, strictly speaking, answering your original question either.

Comment: Writing advice requests are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

> It will help you when you are in need. (correct, polite/formal)
>
> It will help you when it is required. (correct)
>
> It will help you when needed. (correct)
>
> It will help you when you (required) to be helped. (past tense - incorrect)
>   It will help you when you require assistance. (correct tense, altered wording)
>
> It will help you when you are required to do (such task). (awkward; *the* task?)

What is **it** and under what circumstances would **it** be required? The more information you can provide, the better you can be assisted.

Comment: Have a look at my update

Answer (score 0):

## Some alternatives:

> (1) When you need help, I will come into your aid.
>
> (2) Should the necessity arise, I will be delighted to assist you.
>
> (3) If need be, I can also do the job.

Now, taking into account your explanation of the situation it seems like the person you are asking to do the job fears that it [the job] will be entrusted to him alone and that it'll come to form part of his routine. But precisely that is what is intended and he needs to learn how to perform.

Because of that I dared to suggest (3), even when it doesn't comply to your examples and goes into a different meaning.

I agree that some context is needed to determine the correct/*friendlier* expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question to answer as it is not entirely clear what you are trying to say. I think it's something along the lines of:

Should similar circumstances reoccur you will already have the necessary skills.

or

It may be advantageous for you to have this skill set in the future.